# onCreateOptionsMenu inside Fragment - Nullpointerexception while getting menu items

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I need to populate a Spinner from inside a fragment on to `ActionbarSherlock`. Here is what I have done..

Menu XML : main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.icsspinner
        android:id="@+id/menu_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.icsspinner>
</menu>
```

Inside the fragment in `onCreateView` I have used `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` and also overriden the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10) {
        mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(activity, R.array.news_menu,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    }else{
        mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity,
                R.array.news_menu,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner);

    if(spinner == null)
        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Spinner is Null");
    else
        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Spinner is Not Null");

    spinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setSelection(0);
}
```

But the `logcat` shows that the "spinner" is `null`. Any idea on how to get this working and by the way the adapter is where i am populating the `spinner` values from a `string-array` in `strings.xml`

To get the context inside the Fragment, I am using onAttach method,

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

**[EDIT]**

As per @blackbet suggestion, I have modified my `xml` and `onCreateOptionsMenu`. Now the `NullPointerException` is gone, but the `spinner` is `empty`, also I get an overflow icon at the end.

Here is the code change:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10) {
        mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(activity, R.array.news_menu,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    }else{
        mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity,
                R.array.news_menu,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }

    MenuItem menuItem =   menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner);
    IcsSpinner spinner = (IcsSpinner) menuItem.getActionView();

    if(spinner == null)
        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Spinner is Null");
    else
        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Spinner is Not Null");

    spinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setSelection(0);
}
```

main.xml (menu)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item  
        android:id="@+id/menu_spinner"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/layout_config_menu"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</menu>
```

layout_config_menu.xml (in layout folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_action_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is my news_menu string-array

```
<string-array name="news_menu">
    <item>News</item>
    <item>Tour Dates</item>
    <item>Festival News And Rumors</item>
    <item>Late Night Performances</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: the application should also crash

Comment: @blackbelt, yeah it does.. I just avoided posting Logcat as i understand where the problem was.

Comment: Could you tell me what happens if you replace `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner);` with `IcsSpinner spinner = (IcsSpinner) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner);` ?

Comment: I just replaced it. But the same result. The spinner is null

Comment: one thing that I found strange is that icsspinner should be IcsSpinner  and that class is used as custom layout for your item

Comment: @blackbelt, I was using spinner for the first time and I picked up the code from somewhere on SO. But it worked before, while i was testing if i can populate it. I just changed it to IcsSpinner, but still the same problem. spinner is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an entry for your layout file and assign it an actionLayout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  
     <item  
          android:id="@+id/menu_spinner"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/layout_config_menu"  
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     </menu>
```

Inside res/layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
   <com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
     android:id="@+id/my_action_spinner"  
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and inside onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
MenuItem menuItem =   menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner);
IcsSpinner spinner = menuItem.getActionView();
```

Comment: Now the application doesn't crash, thanks for that. But, the spinner is not populated with the values, its just empty. Also I get a overflow icon which is not needed. Any thoughts...